# Leading space and capitalization

Tags: python, regex

How to remove a single space from start of paragraph and capitalize the first letter of paragraph using python?

input:

```
 this is a sample sentence. This is a sample second sentence.
```

Output:

```
This is a sample sentence. This is a sample second sentence.
```

My effort so far:

```
import spacy, re
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp(unicode(open('2.txt').read().decode('utf8')) )
tagged_sent = [(w.text, w.tag_) for w in doc]
normalized_sent = [w.capitalize() if t in ["NN","NNS"] else w for (w,t) in tagged_sent]
normalized_sent1 = normalized_sent[0].capitalize()
string = re.sub(" (?=[\.,'!?:;])", "", ' '.join(normalized_sent1))
rtn = re.split('([.!?] *)', string)
final = ''.join([i.capitalize() for i in rtn])
print final
```

this capitalizes the first word of sentences of all paragraphs except for start of paragraph?

```
Output:
 on the insert tab,  the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document. You can use these galleries to insert tables, headers,  footers,  lists,  cover pages,  and other document building blocks. When you create pictures,  charts,  or diagrams,  they also coordinate with your current document look. 

Expected output:
On the insert tab,  the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document. You can use these galleries to insert tables, headers,  footers,  lists,  cover pages,  and other document building blocks. When you create pictures,  charts,  or diagrams,  they also coordinate with your current document look.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: Define "paragraph".

Comment: Would you be okay with using `nltk` library?

Comment: I have tried it using nltk and it works, porting my functions to spacy.

Comment: Okay, why not `.capitalize()`?

Comment: Actually, i got it working except for minor hiccup for the start of the paragraph, so i thought i could pull it together either with regex or spacy. if other solutions exists please send.

Comment: And `string_reference = string_reference.lstrip('\n')` would kill the leading text space!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirements are only to remove first space and then making first letter capital You can try something like this:

```
your_data='  on the insert tab,  the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document. you can use these galleries to insert tables, headers,  footers,  lists,  cover pages,  and other document building blocks. when you create pictures,  charts,  or diagrams,  they also coordinate with your current document look. '
conversion=list(your_data)
if conversion[0]==' ':
    del conversion[0]

capitalize="".join(conversion).split()
for j,i in enumerate(capitalize):
    try:
        if j==0:
            capitalize[j]=capitalize[j].capitalize()

        if '.' in i:
            capitalize[j + 1] = capitalize[j + 1].capitalize()
    except IndexError:
        pass

print(" ".join(capitalize))
```

output:

```
On the insert tab, the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document. You can use these galleries to insert tables, headers, footers, lists, cover pages, and other document building blocks. When you create pictures, charts, or diagrams, they also coordinate with your current document look.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex and `str.capitalize()`:

```
import re
s = " this is a sample sentence. This is a sample second sentence."
new_s = '. '.join(i.capitalize() for i in re.split('\.\s', re.sub('^\s+', '', s)))
```

Output:

```
'This is a sample sentence. This is a sample second sentence.'
```

Comment: Thanks. But my expected output is:
This is a sample sentence. This is a sample second sentence.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be, (I recommend @Ajax's answer)

```
x = 'on the insert tab,  the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document. You can use these galleries to insert tables, headers,  footers,  lists,  cover pages,  and other document building blocks. When you create pictures,  charts,  or diagrams,  they also coordinate with your current document look. '
print( '. '.join(map(lambda s: s.strip().capitalize(), x.split('.'))))
```

Output:

```
On the insert tab,  the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document. You can use these galleries to insert tables, headers,  footers,  lists,  cover pages,  and other document building blocks. When you create pictures,  charts,  or diagrams,  they also coordinate with your current document look.
```